# Prove that $1\le a_{n} \le 2$ for the following sequence

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Suppose $a_n$ is the sequence satisfying $a_1 = 1 = a_2$ and $a_n = {1\over2}\left(a_{n-1} + {2 \over a_{n-2}}\right)$ for $n \ge3$. Prove that $1\le a_n\le2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My attempt: I decided to proceed by strong induction

Base cases:

Suppose $n = 1$. Then $a_1 = 1$, as required.

Suppose $n = 2$. Then $a_2 = 2$ as required.

Induction Hypothesis: Assume $1\le a_i \le 2$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Induction step: assume $n = k+1$. Then,

$a_{k+1} = {1\over2}\left(a_{k} + {2 \over a_{k-1}}\right) = {a_k\over2} + {1\over a_{k-1}}$

By the IH, $1 \le a_k \le 2$. therfore, ${1\over 2}\le{a_k\over2}\le 1$ and ${1\over 2} \le{1\over a_{k-1}} \le 1 $. Hence, $1 \le {a_k\over2} + {1\over a_{k-1}} \le 2$.

Is this correct?

Comment: seems fine to me

Comment: Minor point: what's the value of $a_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks correct. Wording quibble: by "assume $n=k+1$" you really mean "let $n=k+1$".